# Return custom error from appengine behind Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I am using flask and python 3.6 as a backend service that is deployed to App Engine in GCP. This backend is sitting behind Google Cloud Endpoints deployed in Cloud Run. Endpoints takes all my 404 messages and just returns 404 Not Found. I want to send a more informative error message with the 404 code. Is there any way to do so using my current setup? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom 404 html page:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Then, you need to create 404.html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python Endpoints library to send HTTP error codes with a custom message as  follows:

```
message = 'No entity with the id "%s" exists.' % entity_id
raise endpoints.NotFoundException(message)
```

You can find more info in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/exceptions)